# SqlServer - search if a list of values is fully contained on table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a sql table and a list of values to search.

if at least all the elements of the table are contained in the list, then I must return the Ticket Id (it means that I will update this record). Otherwise, I will return null (it means that it will be a new registration).

For example

[image]

Use cases:

- If I search for this elements: C1, C3, C6, it will be an update and I will get ticketid 1
- If I search for this elements: C8, C3, C6, C10, it will be a create and I will get null as return value

A list of values is a Predefined-Type with a column, in this case, @ElementsToSearch with a column Value

```
SELECT T.Id
FROM 
    Ticket t
INNER JOIN 
    TicketValue TL ON TL.TicketId = T.Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    @ElementsToSearch ES ON ES.Value = TL.Value
WHERE
    ES.Value is null
```

thank you

Comment: what is the output that you are looking for?

Comment: I expect the id of Ticket, in case to update, or null in case to create. I have the rules in the bullets above

Comment: Your case- If I search for this elements: C1, C3, C6, it will be an update and I will get ticketid 1,
But in your table ticketvalue you dont have C6, should it return null or 1?

Comment: Should return a null value !

Comment: @Jcbo . . . Your use cases don't make sense to me.  Both have exactly one match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever you want to return just interchange null and 1

```
declare @ElementsToSearch as Table(value varchar(10))
insert into @ElementsToSearch values('C1'),('C2'),('C3')


SELECT 
CASE WHEN (COUNT(CASE WHEN ES.value IS NULL then 1 end)>0) then NULL else T.id end as output
FROM 
    Ticket t
INNER JOIN 
    TicketValue TL ON TL.TicketId = T.Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    @ElementsToSearch ES ON ES.Value = TL.Value
    group by T.id
```

Comment: hi, in this case it's not working. For this elements I got a NULL value and would be TL1.Id.